# Specifying multiple patterns in a restriction in a XSD

Tags: java, xml, regex, xsd

I have following XSD element:

```
<xsd:element name="password">
    <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <!-- Length check -->
            <xsd:pattern value=".{9,12}" />
            <!-- Format check -->
            <xsd:pattern value=".*\d{2,}.*" />
            <xsd:pattern value=".*[A-Z]{1,}.*" />
            <xsd:pattern value=".*[a-z]{1,}.*" />
            <xsd:pattern value=".*\p{Punct}.*" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>
```

I want to apply each of those patterns individually. It should first check that length is proper. If so then check that it has at least 2 digits and so on. Instead, it concatenates all the expressions together and tries to apply them together.

This is very poor design. If only one pattern is allowed `<xsd:restriction>` should define the cardinality of `<xsd:pattern>` to be **1**. Allowing multiple `<xsd:pattern>` gives the impression that multiple patterns are supported.

**Is there a way to apply multiple patterns to a XSD element?**

Comment: This is a very stupid XSD design decision. Because pattern union you can achieve simply using `|` delimiter in a single pattern element or using `union` on simple types defined for each pattern. So pattern intersection would be logically expected by more pattern elements! The only way how to apply multiple patterns now, is to make a **restriction on a restriction on a restriction...** *THANK you very much, XSD designers!!!*

Answer (score 7):

[**Multiple patterns per restriction**](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/CR-xmlschema11-2-20110721/datatypes.html#rf-pattern) are supported, but they do not mean AND; they mean OR:

> **Note**: An XML `<restriction>` containing more than one `<pattern>` element
> gives rise to a single ·regular expression· in the set; this ·regular
> expression· is an "or" of the ·regular expressions· that are the
> content of the `<pattern>` elements.

If you want multiple regex constraints to apply concurrently, write them in a single `<pattern>`.

For min/max length constraints, rather than using [`<pattern>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#rf-pattern), consider using [`<minLength>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#rf-minLength) and [`<maxLength>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#rf-maxLength) facets.

Comment: Incidentally OR is exactly what I need to allow multiple syntaxes for the same value.