# Specific restrictions

Tags: html, xml, xsd

I was wondering if there was any way to put an enummeration of restrictions in an XSD, let me explain.

There should be 3 posible type of attributes (in this case ID): it can either be "aDigit", "cDigit","mDigit" (Just because I want to create different codes for different type of vehicles)

I have thought of something like this but I know it cannot be done like this.

```
 <xs:attribute name="id" use="required">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:pattern value="c[0-9]"/>
                    <xs:pattern value="a[0-9]"/>
                    <xs:pattern value="m[0-9]"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
 </xs:attribute>
```

Is there any way I could do something like this? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done the way you have shown: see [Specifying multiple patterns in a restriction in a XSD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26992786/specifying-multiple-patterns-in-a-restriction-in-a-xsd)

But more simply you can write `<xs:pattern value="[cam][0-9]"/>`